# Error: Unrecognized option: --packages

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

I'm porting an existing script from BigInsights to Spark on Bluemix.  I'm trying to run the following against Spark on Bluemix:

```
./spark-submit.sh --vcap ./vcap.json --deploy-mode cluster \
    --master https://x.x.x.x:8443 --jars ./truststore.jar \
    --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark_2.10:2.3.0 \
    ./export_to_elasticsearch.py ...
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unrecognized option: --packages
```

How can I pass the `--packages` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix uses a customized Spark version, with a customized `spark-submit.sh` script that only supports a subset of the original script parameters. You can see all the configuration properties and parameters you can use on its [documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic3.html#spark-submit_properties).

Additionally, you can download the Bluemix version of the script from [this link](https://spark-service-attr-yp.ng.bluemix.net/spark_service_attr/spark-submit.sh), and there you can see that there is no argument `--packages`.

Therefore, the problem with your approach is that the Bluemix version of spark-submit does not accept the `--packages` parameter, probably due to security reasons. However, alternatively, you can download the jar for the package you want (and maybe a fat jar for the dependencies) and upload them using the `--jars` parameter. **Note:** To avoid the necessity of uploading the jar files each time you call spark-submit, you can pre-upload them using curl. The details of this procedure can be found on [this link](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic3.html#spark_environment_example).

Comment: Will I just need to download a single jar, or could there be multiple jars for each spark package?

Comment: @SHC That depends. Many packages have been built dependency-free, but there are some that will require you to download the dependencies jars.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, this solution has limitations.  Elasticsearch packaged as a fat jar is around 100Mb making the submit painful slow.

Comment: @SHC Apparently you can upload files up to 200mb via curl, so that you won't need to upload them each time you call spark-submit. More details: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic3.html#spark_environment_example

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Daniel's post, while using the method to pre-upload your package, you might want to upload your package to "${cluster_master_url}/tenant/data/libs", since Spark service sets these four spark properties "spark.driver.extraClassPath", "spark.driver.extraLibraryPath", "spark.executor.extraClassPath", and "spark.executor.extraLibraryPath" to ./data/libs/*

Reference: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic3.html#spark-submit_properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still feels like a clumsy workaround for simply passing a parameter to spark submit :(

Comment: @SHC I don't see it as a workaround. In my opinion, it's how it works in Bluemix. Their Spark was not made to support the `--packages` argument, which makes sense because using it can result in unexpected network traffic, due to large dependency trees, so they decided to remove.

Comment: @DanieldePaula @anh we should probably capture that in the documentation if that was the reason for removing the option.  In the documentation we should also state the alternative approach.  Because we have kept the `spark-submit` name for the script, users will assume the script supports all parameters unless we tell them where that is not the case.

Comment: @SHC Agreed. Personally, I don't like the approach they used, but I understand some of the reasons behind it. Also, I completely agree that the documentation needs improvements.

Comment: Also, packaging fatjars for spark in my experience has been a pita.  Previously, I was about to give up on elasticsearch when I was recommended on their forum to use the `--package` option.

Comment: @SHC: Yeah, I agree. However, Spark on Bluemix apparently is not yet ready for complex applications.